# Python: How to search for a multivalued field in a list WITHOUT more queries?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models in my Django app, Project and ProjectCategory, and Project has this multivalued field *category*.

```
class ProjectCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

class Project(models.Model):
    category = models.ManyToManyField(ProjectCategory)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ...
```

I'm retrieving all Project objects and saving them in a list, called *portfolio*, and now I want to make lists of projects for every category but I want to do it without making any additional queries.

So I have to search for every category if it exists in each project *category* field (this is, searching for an object in a list of objects)

```
portfolio = Project.objects.all().order_by('name')
categories = ProjectCategory.objects.all()
for category in categories:
    portfolio.filter(category__name=category.name)
```

... but I'm new in Python and I don't know how to do it efficiently. I'm not pretty sure if I'm making a new query in the code as it is now. What would be the best approach for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in multiple lookups to .prefetch_related()

```
portfolio = Project.objects.all().order_by('name').prefetch_related()
```

Comment: How does it work? I understand that it "saves" the list, but  when I call .filter() it won't make a new query to the database but will filter in Python instead?

Comment: QuerySets are lazy. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated